# Formatting of values in dynamic Kendo grid

Tags: javascript, asp.net, kendo-grid

I am trying to figure out how to format individual values in a Kendo grid bound to a dynamic data source. 
The challenge is that the columns are not fixed and the format is not even consistent throughout the column.

From what I can tell Kendo supports format strings at the column level using

```
columns:[{field:Name,format:{1:c}}]
```

However this solution is not suitable since it sets the format for the entire column.

I have also found a template based solution that lets you format your data manually using notation like this

```
columns:[{field:Name,template: "#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(SomeDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd')}]
```

However, again this is too hard coded for me since it assumes a single type in the column.

I am looking for a way to specify in the data source itself what the type a value is. Is that possible?

Something like this

```
data = [{field:SomeField,Value:4,Format:{1:c}}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out you can solve this with a custom template. This will run formatting on every value.

```
for (var c = 0; c < grid.Cols.length; c++) {
    grid.Cols[c].template = "#= FormatValue(" + grid.Cols[c].field + ")#";
}


function FormatValue(value) {
    return kendo.toString(value, "c0")//currency formatting 
}
```

Comment: FormatValue needs to be global.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to bind dynamic data source then there in no need to format value in column or feilds. It will automatic adjust with the data. 
You should use this pattern

```
                    fields: {

                                EventID: { editable: true, nullable: false },
                                EventName: { validation: { required: true} },
                                UserID: { validation: { required: true} },
                                EventDate: {  validation: { required: true} },
                                EventTimeFrom: { validation: { required: true} },
                                EventTimeTo: {  validation: { required: true} }
                            }

               columns: [
                        { field: "EventID", title: "Event ID" },
                        { field: "EventName", title: "Event Name" },
                        { field: "UserID", title: "User ID" },
                        { field: "EventDate", title: "Event Date" },
                        { field: "EventTimeFrom", title: "Start Time" },
                        { field: "EventTimeTo", title: "End Time" },
                        ],
```

Comment: If you want to format your currency field then you have to enter this value in that format you want. Like if you want to show your currency like "10,000" then you should enter this value as it is in database.There is nothing like dynamic formatting in KendoUI Grid.